# StageVideo makes mouse appear on a kiosk

Tags: flash, macos, actionscript-3, mouse

I'm developing a kiosk in AS3 that utilizes StageVideo (publishing for FP 10.2 on a Mac Mini). It works fine, except as soon as StageVideo is engaged the mouse becomes visible. This is a public kiosk so I need the mouse to stay hidden.

Has anyone seen this behavior and/or know of a workaround?

Comment: I haven't seen the behavior or worked around it my self, but what comes to mind is try calling Mouse.hide() again, when the StageVideo is shown, or to make a native cursor without visible content (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/native-mouse-cursors.html).

Comment: Thanks. I've tried both of those. I'm wondering if the stage actually loses application focus when Flash accesses the StageVideo layer. Haven't found a workaround yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen magically reappering mouse pointer behaviour on kiosk software I built. I didn't use StageVideo but found similar things happening when interacting with input enabled TextFields.

My solution was to simply put a Timer that called Mouse.hide() every couple of seconds. Hackish, but it worked.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that as well. Part of the issue was the difference between the app running at startup vs. just double clicking it to launch. I ended up with another hack... a java app that runs at startup and moves the mouse to the bottom right of the screen, where it's virtually invisible.